# Is the group of automorphisms of $G$ a subgroup of $S_G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

So my professor randomly wrote on the board: $Aut(G) ≤ S_G$

It wasn't part of a theorem or anything, it was really random, I was just wondering if it was always true or only with specific conditions.

Comment: An automorphism is automatically a bijection, so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every automorphism of $G$ is a bijection, it is certainly a subset of $S_G$. Since the composition of two automorphisms is an automorphism and the inverse of an automorphism an automorphism, it is indeed a subgroup of $S_G$.